# Uso de :after y :before en input

Tags: css3

Hola actualmente estoy trabajando en un **input** quiero tenga solo con un borde en la parte de abajo, lo hago con **:before** porque quiero hacer una animacion con el borde.

El asunto es que no me aparece el borde que estoy creando, la verdad lo intente pero no entiendo porque el **:before** no se ve.

Dejo el codigo, les agradeceria que me dijeran en que falle:

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    align-self: center;
    background: #242526;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
}

.form__group {
    padding: 2rem;
}

.form__group-input {
    background: inherit;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 8px;
}


.form__group-input:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #F84343;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form__group">
            <input type="text" class="form__group-input" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre">
            <!-- <input type="text" class="form__group-input" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre"> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`::after` y `::before` solo funcionan en etiquetas contenedoras, `input` no es contenedora, por ende no es posible utilizar `after` y `before`, puedes utilizar otro contenedor para mostrarlos y darle el efecto que quieres de la siguiente manera:

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    align-self: center;
    background: #242526;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
}

.form__group {
    padding: 2rem;
    position: relative;
}

.form__group-input {
    background: inherit;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 8px;
}


.sub:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #F84343;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form__group">
        <div class="sub">
            <input type="text" class="form__group-input" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre">
            <!-- <input type="text" class="form__group-input" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre"> -->
        </div></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    align-self: center;
    background: #242526;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
}

.form__group {
    padding: 2rem;
}

.form__group-input {
    background: inherit;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 8px;
}


.form__group-input:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #F84343;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form__group">
            <input type="text" class="form__group-input" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre">
            <!-- <input type="text" class="form__group-input" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre"> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Entiendo, ya me hago una idea de que hacer.